# how to concatenate a string and a value for Context.write() in Hadoop 2

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm having some trouble with my output on this reducer using hadoop v2

For some reason if I try to concatenate the String.valueOf(pageRank) onto a string, the updated value is not written to the output. the value 0.15 is written instead for every value. Can anyone help me with this? 
I'll provide more info if it's needed. Thanks!

```
    static class LoopingPRReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
    // The main reduce() function; the input key/value classes must match the first two above, and the key/value classes in your emit() statement must match the latter two above.
    // Make sure that the output key/value classes also match those set in your job's configuration (see below).
    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String outlinks = null;
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (Text value: values) {
            String rank = value.toString();
            if (rank.contains("[")) {
                outlinks = rank;
                continue;
            }
            sum += Double.parseDouble(rank);
        }
        double pageRank = (sum)*0.85+0.15;

        String newRank = "[" + String.valueOf(pageRank)+"]"; //formatted output doesn't work
        context.write(key, new Text(newRank));}
```

Comment: double pageRank = (sum)*0.85+0.15;   is adding .85 to .15 first then multiplying to sum, which is just going to be 1 * sum = sum. Try doing this: (sum * .85) + .15

Comment: Could be. Is that definitely the operator precedence in java?

Comment: You definitely don't need `String.valueOf` since concatenation is doing that for you

Comment: @Alex I think having a bracket just around `(sum)` confuses things. It would be fine without the bracket. Also, the fact you're getting `0.15` as output each time suggests that `sum` may always be `0`.